# Skipping deployment with the npm provider because this branch is not permitted to deploy

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, npm, build-process, travis-ci

I am trying to build and deploy my npm package to npm registry automatically upon push to master branch.

Here is my `.travis.yml` file content:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.11'
- '0.10'
deploy:
  provider: npm
  api_key:
    secure: XXX
  on:
    tags: true
    branch: master
```

The build runs successfully, but the deployment fails with message:

> Skipping deployment with the npm provider because this branch is not permitted to deploy.

Why is that? I tried both without specifying any branch and specifying 'master' branch explicitly.

Here is [the travis build](https://travis-ci.org/ranacseruet/clustered-node/jobs/45905955) status in details.

Any suggestion/clue to solve this issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `tags: true` you specify, that only tagged commits will be deployed. If I'm not mistaken, Travis CI does not explicitly check on which branch such a commit is on. So either specify `tags: true`, then make a tagged commit *OR* specify `branch: master` and commit to this branch to trigger a deployment.

But using both statements won't work.

You can find a note in the [Travis CI documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/) (similar for [GitHub](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases)) stating:

> `tags`: When set to `true`, the application is deployed when a tag is applied to the commit. (Due to a [known issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1675), you should also set `all_branches: true`.)

So the correct answer is to specify either a branch *OR* use `tags: true` and `all_branches: true`.

If you're using GitHub:

> Please note that deploying **GitHub Releases works only for tags**, not for branches.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. However, I tried with only 'tags:true', without branch definition, but unfortunately, that didn't work either. However, now, I tried with only branch definition without tags definition, which worked! What is the problem with tags then?!

Comment: @Rana I just found the answer in the docs, see my update about `all_branches: true`

Comment: Ah! I missed that somehow. Thanks!